# Arrangement of pie charts using matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 7 pi-charts (4 are listed below). I am trying to create a dashboard with 4 pie charts in first row and 3 pie charts in second row. Not sure where I am going wrong with the below code. Are there any other alternatives to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT
fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
line1 = plt.pie(df_14,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('EventLogs')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(223)
line2 = plt.pie(df_24,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('InstalledApp')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(222)
line3 = plt.pie(df_34,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('Drive')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(224)
line4 = plt.pie(df_44,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('SQL Job')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
line5 = plt.pie(df_54,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('Administrators')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
PLT.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better method which I always use and is more intuitive, at-least for me, is to use `subplot2grid`....

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=1600)
#this line will produce a figure which has 2 row 
#and 4 columns 
#(0, 0) specifies the left upper coordinate of your plot
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,0))
plt.pie(df_14,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('EventLogs')
#next one
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 1))
plt.pie(df_24,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('InstalledApp')
```

And you can go on like this, and when you want to switch the row just write the coordinate as (1, 0)... which is second row-first column.

An example with 2 rows and 2 cols -

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=1600)
#2 rows 2 columns

#first row, first column
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(0,0))
plt.pie(df.a,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('EventLogs')

#first row sec column
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 1))
plt.pie(df.a,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('EventLog_2')

#Second row first column
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 0))
plt.pie(df.a,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('InstalledApp')

#second row second column
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1))
plt.pie(df.a,colors=("g","r"))
plt.title('InstalledApp_2')
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Is there a way to set a common legend for all the 7 plots? For example, red as "Not healthy", green as "Healthy"?

Comment: You are looking for `figlegend`, but as each of the plots have their own axes, its not possible to do it with `legend` directly. Or why not just position your legend for one plot?

Comment: I tried this but not working as expected: lgd = plt.legend((line1), ('Helathy','Not Healthy'), loc='upper right')

Comment: This answer, and `subplot2grid`, deserve much more attention. For such a basic task, subplots in Matplotlib are one of the most frustrating things I have to deal with. Bookmarking for future use!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this if you want to create quicker arrangements of subplots**

In addition to hashcode55's code:

When you want to avoid making multiple DataFrames, I recommend to assign integers to your feature-column and iterate through those. Make sure you make a dictionary for the features though.
Here I am doing a plot with 4 columns and 2 rows.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10)) #,dpi=1600)
i= 0 #this is the feature I used
r,c = 0 ,0   #these are the rows(r) and columns(c)

for i in range(7):
  if c < 4:
    #weekday
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (r, c))
    plt.pie(data[data.feature == i].something , labels = ..., autopct='%.0f%%')
    plt.title(feature[i])
    c +=1 #go one column to the left
    i+=1 #go to the next feature
else:
    c = 0 #reset column number as we exceeded 4 columns
    r = 1 #go into the second row
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4), (r, c))
    plt.pie(data[data.feature == i].something , labels = ..., autopct='%.0f%%')
    plt.title(days[i])
    c +=1
    i+=1

plt.show()
```

This code will go on until the amount of features is exhausted.